# Isolating numeric values equation

Tags: php, regex

for a factoring program I'm making I'm wondering if anyone can help me out.

Say I have an equation like

```
5x^2 + 3x + 7
```

I need to isolate 5, 3 and 7

although it could come up with negative signs are oppose to positive signs aswell.

Is there any efficient regex that would do it? as the way I'm doing it right now is fairly long and not very efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try with following regex:**

```
(?:^|[^\^])((?:\- *)?\d+)
```

Combine it with [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function.

**Explanation:**

It matches all digits

```
(\d+)
```

with optional negative sign (whitespacesbetween allowed)

```
(?:\- *)?
```

that are not followed with `^` sign

```
[^\^]
```

or are on the beggining of the string

```
^
```

(so there is `^|[^\^]`) matched in non-captured group

```
(?:^|[^\^])
```

Comment: +1 Very cool, however it does not include negative signs. `(?:^|[^\^])(-?\d+)` should fix that. Though I guess that would require the `-` to be right next to the number... hmm.

Comment: I have also improoved it a bit to allow whitespaces.

Comment: I think an even better solution would be to disallow whitespaces entirely, but remove all whitespaces before running the regex on it. Although PHP tend to be quite forgiving, I don't think it will allow whitespaces within numbers, which is impossible to avoid using a single regex AFAIK.

Comment: Hey I just realized that it's removing the negative signs :S

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to parse it via constructing an expression tree (just like a compiler would). Note that regular expressions or splits won't account for operator precedence, such as `(2 + x)^2`

Basically 5x^2 + 3x + 7 should be parsed as

```
          +
        /   \
      +      7
   /     \
  *        *
 / \      / \
5   ^    3   x
   / \
  x   2
```

However, if you can assume format such as `an x^n + a(n-1) x^(n-1) + ... a1 x + a0` then you can just remove everything you don't need, you can try this

```
$string = '5x^2 + 3x + 7';
$replace = '';
$pattern = '/x(\^(\d)*)?/';

echo preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $string );
// echos 5 + 3 + 7;
```

You should be able to take from there, e.g.

```
$stripped = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $string );
$modified = str_replace( array( '+', '-' ), '|', $stripped );
$parts = explode( '|', $modified );
print_r( $parts );
// should be array( 5, 3, 7 );
```